# Conditional statements in express / jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to use nested conditional statements in jade, but keep getting syntax error.

The following works:

```
if condition != true
  p Hello
  p Hello
```

But when I try add a nested condition, it fails:

```
if condition != true
  p Hello
  if other == true
    p Other
  p Final
```

I am trying to get the equivalent of:

```
if (condition != true) {
  p Hello
  if (other == true) {
    p Other
  }
  p Final
}
```

Depending on my indenting, the 2nd if is either literally translated or I get errors about p Final.

Comment: why are you testing if it's true? just do `if !condition` or `if other`

Comment: I am, just used an expanded version for the example.

Comment: what syntax error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative approach to this:

```
- var content = ""
if other
  content = "Foo"

if condition
  p Hello
  #{content}
```

Answer (score 4):

Indentation is important,

```
    if user.role == 'admin'
     p #{user.name} is an admin
    else
     p= user.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
var sound = "";
if (animal === "pig") {
   sound = "OINK!";
} else if(animal === "cow") {
   sound = "MOOO!";
}
```